# Image popup in a lightbox / overlay from the backend 3.5 admin area (plugin)

Tags: images, admin

Is there a built in way within the backend admin area to have an image show in a popup/lightbox?

I built a plugin with help images and want them to show when clicked in a popup overlay / lightbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the built in ThickBox. Maybe not the pretties library but it does its job.
Just add the class thickbox to the link and add the image to the `href`

Here is a simple example:

```
<?php echo '<a href="image.png" class="thickbox">'. __('Test image', 'domain') .'</a>'; ?>
```

Read more about ThickBox [here](http://thickbox.net/).

Comment: i totally for that...however, I should not have used thickbox i the description. Didn't WP stop using thinkbox? What is default image overly in WP? I was going to use colorbox but did not want to load anymore in the head than aI have to?

Comment: WordPress uses Thickbox for links-popup in the editor, Still in WordPress 3.6-alpha.